# trying to execute simple script on linux vm and getting an error

Tags: python

I am currently teaching myself python and practicing to interact with the linux os. Right now i wanted to make a script, which gives me a .txt file, where the numbers from 1 to 2500 are listed and every number has its own line.
...

my code looks like this and worked perfectly on my windows os, where i wrote it in eclipse.

```
import os 

os.chdir("/home/kali/Desktop/") #in windows i changed pathname to "C:/...."

file = open("thelist.txt", "a")

for x in range(2500):
    file.write(str(x)+"\n")
    
file.close()
```

then i executed it in my terminal with ./script.py (thats what i called it), but i got this error, which i cant explain to myself, because it worked perfectly fine on windows:

```
./script.py: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

thanks for any help

Comment: What happens if you run it with `python script.py` (or `python3 script.py`) instead?

Comment: Alright, then I guess Windows is using the file extension to know which program to use, where linux uses the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20shebang%20is,bang%2C%20or%20hash%2Dpling.) to determine it, you can include one if you still want to run it with `./script.py`